# Using psplot, graphs won't appear on page 2

Tags: pstricks, miktex

The following code seems to work (I'm using Texmaker and MiKTeX):

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\psset{unit=.4cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-11,-11)(11,11)
\psaxes[Dx=5,Dy=5](0,0)(-11,-11)(11,11)
\psplot[plotstyle=curve,linecolor=red]{-2}{2}{2 x 2 exp mul} 
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\psset{unit=.4cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-11,-11)(11,11)
\psaxes[Dx=5,Dy=5](0,0)(-11,-11)(11,11)
\psplot[plotstyle=curve,linecolor=red]{-2}{2}{x 3 exp} 
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I get two graphs on one page. BUT if I change the psset commands to .5cm, so that the second graph is forced to appear on page 2, I get a MiKTeX problem report, as follows:

```
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: Some PostScript specials could not be rendered.
Data: Error: /undefined in tx@Dict
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   PermitFileReading   --nostringval--   PermitFileWriting   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false
   1   %stopped_push   1914   1   3   %oparray_pop   1913   1   3   %oparray_pop
   1897   1   3   %oparray_pop   1787   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--
   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--  --nostringval--
   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1166/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:78/200(L)--
   --dict:95/300(L)--   --dict:37/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript  9.00: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Dvi\Ghostscript.cpp
Line: 372
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Microsoft Windows 7 Business Edition, 64-bit Service Pack 1 (build 7601)
Invokers: explorer/texmaker
SystemAdmin: yes
PowerUser: no
Root0: C:\Users\Ken\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\Ken\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root3: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\Ken\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\Ken\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\Ken\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
```

I'm new to this. Can anybody help me understand what is going on?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: It works for me.  Can you add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` - it puts the versions of the packages used in the log - and edit your answer?

Comment: it looks like that your MiKTeX installtion is not correct configured

Comment: Boris: here's the file list

Comment: *File List*
article.cls 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size12.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pstricks.sty 2011/10/31 v0.52 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
pstricks.tex 2011/09/04 v2.23 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex 2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
xkeyval.sty 2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)
xkeyval.tex 2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
pst-fp.tex 2011/09/04 v2.23 `PST-fp' (hv)

Comment: and here's the rest of it: xcolor.sty 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
dvips.def 1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
pst-plot.sty 2011/04/13 package wrapper for pst-plot.tex (hv)
pst-xkey.sty 2005/11/25 v1.6 package wrapper for pst-xkey.tex (HA)
multido.sty 2004/05/17 package wrapper for PSTricks `multido.tex', (HV/RN)
multido.tex 2010/05/14 v1.42 `multido' (tvz,hv)
pst-plot.tex 2011/11/07 1.34 `pst-plot' (tvz,hv)

Comment: Herbert: I had thought of that so I did a complete reinstall of both MiKTeX and Texmaker. I still get the same result. I do get a (corrupted) .dvi file but there's no graph on the second page--only the axis labels appear (in their correct positions).

Comment: So here is what is now happening: I apply the dvi2ps command to the seemingly corrupt dvi file. This gives me a ps file which GSview shows only the first page of. But then I take this apparent one-page file and run ps2pdf and I get a beautiful-looking 2 page pdf document showing both graphs. So although this is totally mysterious to me I can live with it.

Comment: Another trial and error: remove the current ghostscript and install the newest one.

Comment: New Ghostscript (v 9.04 2011-08-05) doesn't help. It still displays a 1-page .ps document.

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem when compiling your MWE with `0.5cm`. Anyway, you can use `algebraic` option to write `2*x^2` instead of `2 x 2 exp mul`. Use `\newpage` to obtain a new page. And use `figure` to obtain floating figures in your document.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
%\usepackage{pstricks} 
\usepackage{pst-plot} % loads pstricks automatically

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\psset{unit=.4cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-11,-11)(11,11)
\psaxes[Dx=5,Dy=5](0,0)(-11,-11)(11,11)
\psplot[plotstyle=curve,linecolor=red,algebraic]{-2}{2}{2*x^2} 
\end{pspicture}
\caption{Quadratic}
\label{fig:Quadratic}
\end{figure}

\newpage
\begin{figure}
\centering
\psset{unit=.4cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-11,-11)(11,11)
\psaxes[Dx=5,Dy=5](0,0)(-11,-11)(11,11)
\psplot[plotstyle=curve,linecolor=red,algebraic]{-2}{2}{x^3} 
\end{pspicture}
\caption{Cubic}
\label{fig:Cubic}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I copied the above edited version into Texmaker and got the same error.

Comment: You can specify `\psset{algebraic=true}` at the beginning of the document, which means that you don't have to say it every plot